# InfluxDB composite query

Tags: node.js, influxdb

Why this function don't bring the results? In influxdb.

```
select * from items.movement
  where time > now() - 7d
    and oldContainerId='aaaaaa'
    and newContainerId='aaaaaaa'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with this:

```
select * from series
  where time > now() - 7d
    and newContainerId = 'aaaa'
  limit 100;
select * from series
  where time > now() - 7d
    and oldContainerId = 'aaaa'
  limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  from "items.movement" where time > now() - 7d and oldContainerId = 'aaaaaa' and newContainerId = 'aaaaaaa'
```

**NOTE** : Space and double quotes matters.